# why i can pre-compile c'tor of father but not his attribute? cpp

Tags: c++

good morning.
when i tring to pre-compile (i dont know the real name of this..) father c'tor like this:

```
Point_3d(int _x, int _y, int _z) :Point_2d(_x, _y, _z), z(_z+100){};
```

its working.
but when i trieng to do this:

```
Point_3d(int _x, int _y, int _z) :Point_2d(_x, _y, _z), _x(4), z(_z+100){};
```

it doesnt. (the '_x' parameter belongs to the father.)
and another little question:
why cant i pre-compile with '=' and i must use '()'?
thanks!

Comment: Define "pre-compile". In the over 1400 pages that make up the current C++ standard (since you appear to be asking a C++ language question), there is not a single mention of anything that's remotely called a "pre-compile".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `_x(4)` refers to a member of the `Point_2d` class, it can only be initialized by the owning class, not by derived classes.

The initalizer list can contain base classes and members of the current class, not members of base classes.

But wouldn't

```
Point_3d(int _x, int _y, int _z) :Point_2d(4, _y, _z), z(_z+100){};
___________________________________________^
```

do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you to do two things. First give full code and second please check about pre-compile term.
  If I guess, _x, and_y are base class members and _z is derived class member

1. `Point_3d(int _x, int _y, int _z) :Point_2d(_x, _y, _z), z(_z+100){};`

will work coz you are *initializing*  z(member of derived class) from derived class constructor.

2. `Point_3d(int _x, int _y, int _z) :Point_2d(_x, _y, _z), _x(4), z(_z+100){};`

is not working coz you are trying to *initialize* _x(base class member) from derived class constructor which is illegal.
  Although you can do something for code snippet 2

3. `Point_3d(int x, int y, int z) :Point_2d(x, y, z), _z(z + 100) { _x = 2; }`

Here _x (base class member) is not being *initialized* in derived class constructor but it is being assigned (provided _x is in public scope).